# async / await doesn't seem to work nodejs passport reset passwd

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

For some reason i get this Error :

Error: req#login requires a callback function
at IncomingMessage.req.login.req.logIn (/home/project/node_modules/passport/lib/http/request.js:47:44)
at exports.update (/home/project/controllers/authController.js:92:13)
at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)

with this code:

```
exports.update = async (req, res) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({
  resetPasswordToken: req.params.token,
  resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() }
  });

  if (!user) {
    req.flash('error', 'Password reset is invalid or has expired');
    return res.redirect('/login');
  }

  const setPassword = promisify(user.setPassword, user);
  await setPassword(req.body.password);
  user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
  user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;
  const updatedUser = await user.save();
  await req.login(updatedUser);
  req.flash('success', 'Your password has been reset! You are now 
logged in!');
  res.redirect('/');
};
```

What am i doing wrong ? I can't figure it out ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the error message, `req.login(updatedUser);` expects a callback as the second argument. Basically, you'd do something like this:

```
req.login(updatedUser, function(err, data) {
  // handle err and data
});
```

However, since you wish to `await` on this async operation, you need something that returns a promise. Basically, you can await on any value that is a promise (and `login` does not return one.

You can build a promise around this call like this:

```
await new Promise(function(res, rej) {
  req.login(updatedUser, function(err, data) {
    if (err) rej(err);
    else res(data);
  });
})
```

Node.JS ships with a helper function named [promisify](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) to help constructing this behavior if you do not wish to do this manually everytime.

Answer (score 3):

Exactly as `Ekin Konc` answered you can only `async/await` only functions that returns a `Promise`.

You can write some middleware to alias your `req.login` to promisified function.

E.g

`loginPromisifier.js`

```
const { promisify } = require('util');

const loginPromisifier = (req,res,next)=>{
  req.login = promisify(req.login);
  next();
}

module.exports = loginPromisifier;
```

and then `app.js`

```
const loginPromisifier = require(./loginPromisifier) // your path to it
app.use(loginPromisifier);
```

I hope that helped.